# Ghidra function pointers to another file in project

Tags: ghidra

Given a function pointer which is obtained dynamically using dlsym, how can I tell Ghidra that that pointer points to a function in another .so that I have open in same project for which I have already done some parameter renaming etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the function pointer to where the actual function's address is in your first binary, you should see something similar to this.

```
00870808 09 00 00 80     addr      <EXTERNAL>::Function_Something
```

Right click the operand (the `<EXTERNAL>...` part) and select '*Edit External Location*'. A new dialog window will pop up.

In this window, click the '*Edit*' button next to the '*Path*' field and select your `.so` file.